# Can we setup a HLF network with one partner with HLF 2.x and another partner with HLF 1.4.1?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have a HLF network running in 1.4.1 with simulated partner. I want to upgrade the network at my side to 2.x and keep the partner version as it is. Is it possible? What steps we need to follow to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Channel capabilities apply to both the orderers and the peers and must be supported by both. So both of you and orderers & peers should match the channel definition.

```
Capabilities:
# Channel capabilities apply to both the orderers and the peers and must be
# supported by both.
# Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
    # V2_0 capability ensures that orderers and peers behave according
    # to v2.0 channel capabilities. Orderers and peers from
    # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
    # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 capability.
    # Prior to enabling V2.0 channel capabilities, ensure that all
    # orderers and peers on a channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
    V2_0: true

# Orderer capabilities apply only to the orderers, and may be safely
# used with prior release peers.
# Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
    # V2_0 orderer capability ensures that orderers behave according
    # to v2.0 orderer capabilities. Orderers from
    # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
    # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 orderer capability.
    # Prior to enabling V2.0 orderer capabilities, ensure that all
    # orderers on channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
    V2_0: true

# Application capabilities apply only to the peer network, and may be safely
# used with prior release orderers.
# Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
    # V2_0 application capability ensures that peers behave according
    # to v2.0 application capabilities. Peers from
    # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
    # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 application capability.
    # Prior to enabling V2.0 application capabilities, ensure that all
    # peers on channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
    V2_0: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Running multiple versions of peers (and orderers) in the same network is fully supported as Fabric was designed with this in mind.  It is actually typical to perform rolling upgrades across a network.

Fabric supports this be using [channel capabilities](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.3/capabilities_concept.html?highlight=channel%20capabilities%27#channel-capabilities) which ensure that all peers on any given channel will be able to process transactions.  If a peer does not meet the minimum capabilities defined for a channel, it will halt processing of transactions on that channel.  In your case, you would NOT update the channel capabilities until all peers / orgs in the network upgrade to v2.x.  So you can upgrade your org's peers to v2.x but would not upgrade the channel capabilities for any channel which has v1.4.x peers.

I'd recommend upgrading your org's peers to the latest 1.4.x release first and then upgrading to v2.x.  You will also want to have a look at the [docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.3/upgrade_to_newest_version.html#upgrading-to-2-2-from-the-1-4-x-long-term-support-release) for upgrading from v1.4.x to v2.2.x.  If your chaincode is written in Go, pay particular attention to the [chaincode shim](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.3/upgrade_to_newest_version.html#chaincode-shim-changes-go-chaincode-only) section as you'll need to make sure your org's 2.2.x peers can (re)build the v1.4.x chaincode.  You would do this by overriding the default value for the `ccenv` [config](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-2.2/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L532) / environment variable and setting it to the v1.4.x version of the image.